# How can I edit a file on a GPT partition, SLAX linux

Tags: gpt, slax

I have installed ESXi v5.5 on a white box and need to insert a particular parameter into the boot.cfg file. I created a bootable USB drive (SLAX Linux) and can see the device /dev/sda, but can't mount it.

Using parted I can list the partitions on the disk - and can see the partition I want to access, but can't figure out how to gain access at the file level so I can edit the boot.cfg file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: give us the output of `cat /proc/partitions`

Answer (score 2):

You need to mount a filesystem to access files on it, same as always.

Does the kernel recognize the partitions, e.g. have partition device files like `/dev/sda1` been created?  If so, the fact that it's GPT is irrelevant; just mount the partitions as usual.  If not, your kernel may lack GPT support.